# Массовый редирект по списку

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Подскажите пожалуйста, как организовать массовый редирект если есть старый список урлов и есть новый список урлов.

Я читал [Блог Девака](https://devaka.ru/articles/redirects-with-url-map), 
но так и не понял, как правильно реализовать.

У меня есть 2 файл `old_url` и файл `new_url.txt` соответственно, но как это применить в файле `.htaccess`?

Comment: А можно увидеть примеры `url`? они в чем то похожи друг на друга?

Comment: old:http://turkishserial.ru/zapretnaya-lyubov/215-zapretnaya-lyubov-1-seriya.html
new:http://turkishserial.ru/zapretnaya-lyubov/351-zapretnaja-ljubov-1-serija.html

Comment: Вы не поняли мой вопрос, дайте массив старого и нового, а не один урл

Comment: Я уже поправил: